# solving diffusion equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to find a solution for

$u_{t}=u_{xx} $

$u_{0}(x)=[A|_{t=0}]xe^{[-f|_{t=0}]x^2}$

So in order to reach for the solution the following steps were done:

$\frac{∂u}{∂t} =A_t(t)xe^{-f(t)x^2}-f_t(t)A(t)x^3e^{-fx^2}$

$\frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2} =2fAx(2fx^2-3)e^{-fx^2}$

Then equating the two

$A_txe^{-fx^2}-f_tAx^3e^{-fx^2}=2fAx(2fx^2-3)e^{-fx^2}$

follows that,

$A_t=-6fA; -f_t=4f^2$

But how does it follow?

For example I'm getting this equation

$-f_tAx^3e^{-fx^2}=2fAx(2fx^2-3)e^{-fx^2}-A_txe^{-fx^2}$

But how does $-f_t=4f^2$ come from it?

Comment: I'm confused by your notation. Is it $u_0(x)=c_1 x e^{-c_2 x^2}$ for some constants $c_1,c_2$? Are you then assuming a solution of the form $f(t) x e^{-g(t) x^2}$ and trying to determine $f(t),g(t)$?

Comment: yes indeed @ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation basically describes time-dependent polynomials in $x$ once you divide by $e^{-fx^2}$:

$$(-f_t A) x^3 + A_t x = (4f^2 A)  x^3 - 6fA x.$$

For these to be equal, the cubic coefficients and the linear coefficients must be equal, which yields the equations for the evolution of $f$ and $A$.

Comment: What if $c1, c2$ were not constants but $A1(t), A2(t)$, how then it should be solved?

Comment: @DannyDan That doesn't really make sense; when I introduced $c_1,c_2$ in my comment above, it was in reference to the initial data, which obviously can only depend on $x$. If you allowed those to depend on $x$ on the other hand then this method has no chance to work smoothly without some very restrictive assumptions on how that dependence can manifest itself.

Comment: sorry I meant: $u(x,t)=A_1(t)xe^{-A_2(t)x^2}$ instead of the initial condition $u_0(x)$

Comment: @DannyDan That is the assumption being made, but it only makes sense in the context of an initial condition of the form $c_1 x e^{-c_2 x^2}$.